# Ajax calls not executed in the right order

Tags: javascript, ajax

I had similar problems before: e.g.:

```
{
sendMailToAdmin();
sendMailToUser();
redirect();
}
```

and the redirect would happen before the Mail to the user is sent.
`sendMailToUser()` contains an AJAX call. I solved the problem by placing `(success:redirect())` in the Ajax call of `sendMailtoUser()` instead of where it was in the code above.

Now I have a similar problem but the same solution is not working:

```
function sendDeletionMailToMember()
        {
            var data = "userEmail=" + "<?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?>";            
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'stcg-json-responses.php?fct=sendDeletionMailToMember',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: deleteMember()
            });
        };
```

The e-mail should include some of the users data from the database. After the mail is sent `success: deleteMember()` is called to delete all the users data. The order of execution is important because once `deleteMember()` is executed I cannot add the data from the database into the mail any longer.

However the mail is sent, the user is deleted but the data I need to extract from the database into the mail is missing in the mail. Looks like the `deleteMember()`executes too fast. I tried with `async:false`but it die not change anything

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are calling `deleteMember()` immediately when you should be providing it as a callback.

Try `success: deleteMember`, i.e. without the parentheses.

Alternately:

```
success: function() { deleteMember(); }
```